# How to open current path when creating a new tab in gnome terminal when using csh shell?

Tags: linux, bash, centos, gnome-terminal, csh

I'm on CentOS 7.9 (Gnome Terminal 3.28.2) with `csh` (yeah I know but work requirement) as my default shell. My problem is this: whenever I open a new tab in gnome terminal, the new tab redirects to `~/`, rather than preserving the path of the old path. Say I'm currently at `/home/myself/project1/src/`, I'd like my new tab to also be at `/home/myself/project1/src/`, not back to `/home/myself`.

On our super old CentOS 6.10 machines (Gnome Terminal 2.31.3) where users are also using `csh` as default, new tabs do preserve old paths as we want it.

Meanwhile, `bash` doesn't show any problems. Whether on 6.10 or 7.9, users using `bash` as the default shell always keep their old path when opening new tabs.

It seems like my issue is both related to the shell *and* Gnome Terminal. Frustratingly, the `/etc/csh.cshrc` files on both CentOS 6.10 and 7.9 machines look the same, and I failed to find any toggles in Gnome Terminal's preferences.

So back to the title, when using `csh` how can I let a new tab open start from the path of the old tab in gnome terminal instead of going back to `~/`? Many Thanks!

Comment: When you just start a new `csh` shell, is your path preserved?

Comment: @aviro Hi, I always start a new shell by right-clicking my mouse and choose _Open Terminal_ (when right-clicking on the Desktop) or _Open in Terminal_ (when right-clicking in a folder). _Open Terminal_ starts the shell at `~`, whereas _Open in Terminal_ starts the shell at wherever I opened it (`~/Documents` for example). New tabs will always start at wherever the new shell started. If the new shell window started at `~/Documents`, and I `cd` to `~/Documents/project1`, then open a new tab, the new tab will start at `~/Documents`, not `project1`

Answer (score 0):

You need to emit the OSC 7 escape sequence, with its parameter being the URI of the current working directory, in URI-encoded format. This tells the terminal emulator what the working directory is, and thus in turn lets it launch new tabs/windows in that same directory.

You might want to look at `/etc/profile.d/vte.csh` and `/etc/profile.d/vte-2.91.sh` for an idea how to do this, including the use of the helper binary `/usr/libexec/vte-urlencode-cwd` that performs URI-encoding. The exact pathnames might slightly vary across systems.

`/etc/profile.d/vte.csh` seems to check for the shell being `tcsh`. I don't know if it uses anything that wouldn't work for plain old `csh`, or how to hook it up in `csh` to some appropriate place (e.g. when the prompt is printed, or when the directory is changed). Or maybe it works in `csh` as well, you just have to remove the `tcsh` check. I'm not familiar with `csh` or `tcsh` at all, so I leave this part for you as an exercise.